# Is auto-scrolling content bad practice accessibility-wise?

Tags: accessibility, user-experience

Is it ok in regards to accessibility to scroll content into view? Is it disorienting for some users to have the page move by itself?

For instance, if a dropdown opens and only a few options are visible, is it better to let the user scroll the whole dropdown into view or to do this programmatically?

Scrolling into view seems like a nice UX improvement (we're avoiding an extra action from the user) but also possibly important accessibility-wise (the user might not realize there is important content below the fold, so we're making sure they see it).

On the other hand, moving the whole page seems like it could be jarring to some user, who may lose track of where they are on the page...

Answer (score 1):

Good question. There may be some that benefit from it, but others will definitely find it disorientating.

Without knowing more about the actual case, I would default to **not** auto-scrolling, because auto-animation requires a number of other things to be in place.

There are some WCAG rules which only apply when there is automatic movement. (e.g. https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/pause-stop-hide)

Also the fact there's a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) to accommodate this kind of thing shows that this is a feature that some users will prefer to avoid.

If you're using a CSS transition to handle this, it should be quite easy to put it in a `prefers-reduced-motion` media query, and the browser preferences would offer a mechanism to switch off the feature, making it compliant with SC 2.2.2

Even if you're doing the scrolling entirely with javaScript, [you can still access the media query](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/posts/prefers-reduced-motion/).

As an alternative, or even as an additional hint (belt and braces), you might consider adding a visual affordance to the last visible item indicating "more...". I have seen this handled with an ellipsis, or downward-pointing triangle/caret, but those idioms aren't strongly established for this kind of thing.

Screen reader users may be at a small advantage here. If you've marked up your popup correctly, the AT will announce the number of items, visible or not. :)

Good luck!